# Framer-motion scrollYProgress not triggering on Nextjs 14.1.0 page.jsx

Tags: css, reactjs, next.js, react-hooks, framer-motion

** Am experience no scroll trigger animation switch from the y-scroll to x-scroll automatically using framer motion in nextjs 14.1.0, does anyone know the solution or what I may be missing in this project  I'd highly appreciate **

```
const targetRef = useRef(null);
const { scrollYProgress } = useScroll({ target: targetRef});
  const x = useTransform(scrollYProgress, [0, 1], ["0%", "-100%"]);

  return (
    <motion.div  className="h-full"
  initial={{y:"-200vh"}}
  animate={{y:"0%"}}
  transition={{duration:0.7, ease: "easeIn"}}
  >
    <div className='h-[600vh]' ref={targetRef}>
      <div className="w-screen h-[calc(100vh-5rem)] flex items-center justify-center text-center text-black text-6xl">
        Shall We Go through My Portfolio?
        </div>
        <div className=" sticky top-0 flex h-screen gap-4 items-center overflow-hidden" >
          <motion.div style={{ x }} className='flex'>
          {/*<div className="flex items-center justify-center w-screen h-screen bg-gradient-to-r from-purple-300 to-red-300" />*/}
          {itemz.map((item)=>(
            <div className={`h-screen w-screen flex items-center justify-center bg-gradient-to-r ${item.color}`} key={item.id}>
            <div className='flex flex-col gap-8 text-white'>
              <h1 className='text-2xl font-semibold '>{item.title}</h1>
              <div className='relative w-80 h-56 md:w-96 md:h-64 lg:w-[500px] lg:h-[350px] xl:w-[600px] xl:h-[420px]'>
                <Image
                src={item.img}
                fill
                alt={`portfolio ${item.title}`}
                />
              </div>
              <p>{item.desc}</p>
              <Link target='_blank' href={item.link}>
              <button>Visit Site</button>
              </Link>
            </div>
             </div>
             ))}
             </motion.div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </motion.div>
    
  )
}

export default Experience
```

Comment: seems it is known bug, check this link :  https://github.com/framer/motion/issues/2398